# Display Field Based on Radio Selection

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a Woocommerce site where my client would like it so that if the **"every month"** radio button gets selected then **.wapf-wrapper** will appear.

I've tried multiple solutions but they are not working. This is the code I've I'm working with currently:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="convert_to_sub_36"]:radio').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("1_month");
    var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
    $(".wapf-input").not(targetBox).hide();
    $(targetBox).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.wapf-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <span>Choose a purchase plan:</span>
  <ul class="wcsatt-options-product wcsatt-options-product--">
    <li class="one-time-option">
      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub_36" data-custom_data="[]" value="0" checked="checked">
                        <span class="one-time-option-details">one time</span>
                                            </label>
    </li>
    <li class="subscription-option">
      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub_36" value="1_month">
                        <span class="subscription-option-details"><span class="no-price subscription-price"><span class="subscription-details">every month</span></span></span>
                                            </label>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="wapf-wrapper">
    <div class="wapf-field-group" data-group="74">

      <div class="wapf-field-row">
        <div class="wapf-field-container wapf-field-radio" style="width:100%;" for="5f87355d578fd">

          <div class="wapf-field-label wapf--above"><label><span>Agency</span></label></div>
          <div class="wapf-field-input">
            <div class="wapf-radios">
              <label for="71955" class="wapf-input-label"><input id="71955" name="wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]" class="wapf-input" type="radio" data-field-id="5f87355d578fd" value="mwh9o"><span class="wapf-label-text">Lifebridge</span></label>
              <label for="93527" class="wapf-input-label"><input id="93527" name="wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]" class="wapf-input" type="radio" data-field-id="5f87355d578fd" value="hrv77"><span class="wapf-label-text">Beverly Bootstraps</span></label>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div><input type="hidden" value="74" name="wapf_field_groups"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can see the product [here](https://rootmeals.wpengine.com/product/meals-donation/).

Comment: try using `$(document).ajaxComplete` instead of  `.ready` since the `.wapf-input` isn't added until after the choice is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vanilla JS (add it to the end of your JS file):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const wapf = document.querySelector(".wapf-wrapper");

  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target && e.target.name == "convert_to_sub_36") {
      wapf.style.display = e.target.value === "1_month" ? "block" : "none";
    }
  });
});
```

You can see it in action here - https://codepen.io/ivanduka/pen/eYzJBJv?editors=1111

Comment: I tested this out on the staging site and it did not work. Here is the staging site: rootmeals.wpengine.com/product/meals-donation If you select the donation amount and then select "every month" the .wapf-wrapper is not appearing.

Comment: Are you positive that the code is executed on your staging website? I don't see my code in the Sources tab of the Chrome Dev Tools. What is the name of the file where you added the code and to which folder?

Comment: Actually I see the code from another answer, and it does not work, but I do not see my code there. Maybe you forgot to hit save or something like that?

Comment: Sorry I removed it temporarily to test out the other answers code. I've added your code back to the site.

Comment: Well, I see the potential problem right there. Your radiobuttons "one time" and "Monthly" are not shown right away when the page is loaded. Let me update my solution in a couple of minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggle` and pass it a boolean (true/false) to show/hide.

Single line: `$(".wapf-wrapper").toggle(($(this).val() == "1_month"));`

I also changed the click event to change since that is the appropriate event for radio/checkboxes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change",'input[name="convert_to_sub_36"]',function() {
    $(".wapf-wrapper").toggle(($(this).val() == "1_month"));
    /*
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("1_month");
    var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
    $(".wapf-input").not(targetBox).hide();
    $(targetBox).show();*/
  });
});
```

```css
.wapf-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <span>Choose a purchase plan:</span>
  <ul class="wcsatt-options-product wcsatt-options-product--">
    <li class="one-time-option">
      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub_36" data-custom_data="[]" value="0" checked="checked">
                        <span class="one-time-option-details">one time</span>
                                            </label>
    </li>
    <li class="subscription-option">
      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub_36" value="1_month">
                        <span class="subscription-option-details"><span class="no-price subscription-price"><span class="subscription-details">every month</span></span></span>
                                            </label>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="wapf-wrapper">
    <div class="wapf-field-group" data-group="74">

      <div class="wapf-field-row">
        <div class="wapf-field-container wapf-field-radio" style="width:100%;" for="5f87355d578fd">

          <div class="wapf-field-label wapf--above"><label><span>Agency</span></label></div>
          <div class="wapf-field-input">
            <div class="wapf-radios">
              <label for="71955" class="wapf-input-label"><input id="71955" name="wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]" class="wapf-input" type="radio" data-field-id="5f87355d578fd" value="mwh9o"><span class="wapf-label-text">Lifebridge</span></label>
              <label for="93527" class="wapf-input-label"><input id="93527" name="wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]" class="wapf-input" type="radio" data-field-id="5f87355d578fd" value="hrv77"><span class="wapf-label-text">Beverly Bootstraps</span></label>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div><input type="hidden" value="74" name="wapf_field_groups"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've added your code and it does not appear to be working on the staging site https://rootmeals.wpengine.com/product/meals-donation/ If you select the donation amount and then select "every month" the .wapf-wrapper is not appearing.

Comment: @FeliciaSantos I updated my answer to delegate the handling of the radio, it should work now.